# Make namespaces backwards compatible in PHP

Tags: php

So I was reading about PHP namespaces, and I realized that in versions earlier than 5.3, if you write

```
namespace MyNamespace
```

you get a parse error.

Is there any way to avoid this i.e. make namespaces backwards-compatible, so the code doesn't simply crash?

Comment: You're describing forward  compatibility.

Comment: The question is how to make new code work with old versions of PHP. Sounds like backward compatibility to me...

Comment: The question is how to make old versions of PHP run code intended for newer versions. That's forward compatibility.

Comment: @echo: Wouldn't you consider asking if a blu-ray movie (namespaces) can work with a dvd player (old php versions) asking about forward compatibility?

Comment: "The question is how to make new code work with old versions of PHP." Backwards compatibility is making old code work with new versions of PHP.

Comment: @everyone. I think he's got it now :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short Answer: No.

Longer Answer: (added to capture useful information from other deleted answers).  The new Syntax will cause parse errors in PHP, so you can't use a customer error handler to catch errors generated in versions < 5.3.  In theory you could write a pre-processor the scans and/or does a lex/parse on the source and then write something back out that would be PHP 5.2 compatible, but that creates more problems than it solves.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could query the version of PHP being used and call eval if it's high enough. I don't know if that will work though.

Comment: I don't think that would work.  Namespaces are resolved at compile (well parse) time, whereas eval is resolved at run time...

Comment: I thought that it could perform certain compile-time magicks, and that's why it can't be called from a variable function.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I think it's possible, but I don't believe it's worth it. The idea would be to create a custom default [stream wrapper](http://www.php.net/manual/en/stream.streamwrapper.example-1.php), which will parse PHP files according to the new grammar and make the appropriate changes to the syntax so that it will be valid PHP < 5.3.

The wrapper would have to replace class names such as `Foo\Bar\Baz` with `Foo_Bar_Baz`. Currently I'm not sure if there's something that would render this impossible.

Anyway, I don't believe it's worth the effort. Upgrade to PHP 5.3.

Oh, that means that the wrapper code should be compatible with PHP < 5.3.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very old question, but I needed to make a couple of instructions with namespaces backward compatible with a very old PHP installation (5.2).

What I finally did to avoid parse errors was:

```
if(version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.3.0') >= 0) {
    include("file_with_namespaces_code.php");
}
else{
    echo("put php 5.2 code here");
}
```