# class namespace in older PHP versions

Tags: php, namespaces

I really would like to adopt namespaces into my workflow. As i understand it PHP 5.3.0+ supports this. Is there a way to replicate PHP namespace for older versions of PHP?

Comment: *Exact duplicate:* http://stackoverflow.com/q/2908363/1563422

Comment: it's worth mentioning that PHP 5.3 has been available for five years now, and PHP5.2 was declared end-of-life over two years ago. If you're still on 5.2 or earlier, you're on an unsupported version that has known security issues which are not going to be fixed. You *really* need to upgrade rather than trying to force an old version of PHP to do new stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there isn't, There's no such thing as forward compatibility.

Upgrading to a more recent version of PHP is your only sensible solution.